# Creating a Loop that checks for instock items on a webpage using a javascript file

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, full-text-search, reload

I have been trying to create a Javascript simple program that checks for words on a specific web page and I am just wanting it to check every 5 seconds or so if the words are there.  I think I have the pieces of the puzzle but I just cant put it together. I am a beginner at best and don't understand why this code is not working.

This is what I have but the iteration after searching for the word and reloading the page to check again are not in sync and the page reloads once. It should be checking if word is there, if it is there then I am trying to get it to reload page and check again and loop again .... every 5 seconds. Current output with below code is "true" in an alert box twice then reload after 5 seconds once. And it's over.

Note:

- x just stops from looping forever.
- When it doesn't match any more it plays a song.
- I saved this as a .js file and I am currently just testing the code within chrome dev tools.
  '''

  ```
    var x = 1;
    function ol(){
    do {
        if (document.documentElement.outerHTML.search('8&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\\\\&quot;stock out-of-stock') != -1)
        {
            x=x+1;
           alert("true");
            window.setTimeout(function ol() {
            window.location.reload(true);
            }, 5000);
            } else {
            alert("NOT FOUND!");
            var snd1 = new Audio("C:\Users\DL\Desktop\bot files\BattleMetal-320bit.mp3");
            function beep1() 
            {alert()
                snd1.play()
                beep1()
            }

        }
   }while(x<3 && document.documentElement.outerHTML.search('8&quot;},&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;<p class=\\\\&quot;stock out-of-stock') != -1);
  ```

  }
  ol();

Answer (score 0):

In the while condition you are checking if x < 3. so after printing twice true you are explicitly stopping  the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the respone.  Yes that is true.  I am trying to get the Page Reload to Reload after checking when word has been found.  Currently it is looping without page reloading and reloading once after it loops 3 times.  I guess technically it needs to break the loop if word is found and then reloads the page , over and over until the word is not found.  Ignore the x<3 part because I have that in there just to see if it reloads the page every time and also to stop the loop until I figure this out.